# Given some data, is there a measure of convexity

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

If we have some data of a function that maps $X \in R^D$ to $y \in R$, can we have a measure of convexity for it?

For example for three points, I can imagine a line passes through two of them, and if the third point is in between, it's positive distance to the line could be a measure of convexity.

or if we can define a convex surface and compute the distance between the points to this surface

Comment: One simple strategy is to compare the function to its [lower convex envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_convex_envelope), which can be computed using convex hull algorithms. However, this is much more sensitive to negative outliers (i.e. if a point is lower than the envelope of the rest) than to positive outliers. For a more symmetric measure, you could try computing the least-squares convex fit and comparing with that; see Sec. 6.5.5 of [Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/).